# Chrome extension,force chrome to open url on start

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension,as its part i want to open a saved url in local storage when the chrome starts . Ie, when a user initially(in a day) click on chrome, i want to open a url in new window without being clicked on the extension. is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `window.open("URL to open", '_blank');` will open the window.

Comment: Yes..and its fixed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you're looking for is [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create). This will open an new tab with a specified URL.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: localStorage.getItem('urlLocalStorageKey')})
```

If you want it to open in a new windows then you'll need [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create).

```
chrome.windows.create({url: [localStorage.getItem('urlLocalStorageKey')]})
```

For both of these approaches you'll need to add the `tabs` permission to your manifest.

If you implement either of these in your extensions background script then they will run when Chrome opens.

Comment: But how can i identify the user opens chrome browser ? is there any event for that ?

Comment: [chrome.runtime.onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) might be what you're after.